# Incorrect syntax near '='. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have problem, when count the quantity column value where its  email, the  email i got from session["email"], before i do try and catch there error at int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();, this their error message "Incorrect syntax near '='. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception". i need to count number of quantity from my table. data type for menu_quantity is float.

[image]

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["email"] != null)
        {
            A();
            //lbltotalitemcart.Text = A().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lbltotalitemcart.Text = "login email first";
        }

    }
```

---

```
 public int A()
    {
        String email = Request.QueryString["email"];
        string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(menu_quantity) FROM cart Where email=" + email + "";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
           ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    return count;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lbltotalitemcart.Text = e.ToString();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `email` is probably a string so you need `email = '" + email + "'...`. But instead of solving this have a look at parameterized queries so not to be in risk of sql injections

Comment: Extremely relevant to the SQL Injection issue. https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Comment: i got the answer,  change to string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(menu_quantity) FROM cart Where email=@email"; and cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["email"].ToString());

Comment: obligatory: https://www.xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missin `'` before and after `email`:

```
SELECT COUNT(menu_quantity) FROM cart Where email='" + email + "'";
```

However its not a good way of executing a query. instead, Use `SqlCommand.Parameters`:

```
string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(menu_quantity) FROM cart Where email=@email"
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
           ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
 {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, con)
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
       con.Open();
       int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       return count;
 }
```

Comment: I personally feel that an answer for this question without showing the use of parameterized queries is a bad answer

Comment: Someone with your rep should know the answer is to use parameters.

Comment: I edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not super familiar with ASP syntax. But my gut SQL knowledge is telling me you're missing quotes around the email in the query itself.

Comment: While this is absolutely the cause, direction should provided to correcting the SQL Injection issue as well.